# JasperReports: Chart in every row

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I want to add a x-y-Chart to every row. The datasource of the report is a bean collection. So the data of each row is represented by a bean. The data of the chart of a row should be extracted from two arrays (one array contains the x data, another the y data). How can I implement this? The tutorials I found only show how to create a single chart for the whole report.

Comment: I am don't understand. Every bean contain x[] and y[]? Is it right? And you want display chart for every bean in collection?

Comment: you're absolutely right

Answer (score 1):

Make subreport with parameter (bean). Subreport place in detail band of main report.
In subreport make chart for one bean in summary band